# Meaning of TROP in comments

Tags: vocabulaire, argot

I someone comments TROP in all capital letters as a single word response to a YouTube Video followed by a emoji of a goat.
Is this a negative or positive response.

Comment: Salut Elias.  This would benefit from more context and please do include what you've found in the dictionary.  That way we can help you with where you're stuck.  Please take a moment to [tour] and see the [help] et bienvenue.

Comment: @livresque Je dirais que ce serait difficile de répondre à la question à l'aide d'un dictionnaire seulement :) Mon instinct serait de dire que "trop" ici veut dire qqch comme "c'est trop bon / amusant" et que l'emoji de chèvre signifie GOAT (greatest of all time, avec la force de "grand réussite"), mais je n'ai pas les connaissances culturelles pour vérifier que cela s'exprime comme ça en français ...

Comment: @LukeSawczak Oui c'est ça mais il faut le contexte (réussir ou rater) sinon c'est peu clair.  Au moins on peut dire "normalement trop veut dire X mais pourquoi...?" pour clarifier le problème.

Answer (score 1):

> L’acronyme [GOAT](https://www.gentside.com/argot/goat-ca-veut-dire-quoi_art98575.html) est employé pour désigner quelqu’un qui est le
> meilleur dans son domaine. **Sur les réseaux sociaux, les utilisateurs
> mettent l’emoji chèvre  au lieu d’écrire le mot GOAT.** Puisque sans
> majuscule, goat en anglais veut dire chèvre.

---

> The acronym GOAT is used to say someone is the best in the field.  On
> social media, users put the emoji of a goat instead of writing it out.
> In English, without all caps, the word is spelled and pronounced the same as the
> animal.
>
> However, it wasn't always popular as a compliment, and some may find
> it too arrogant or expressing too much confidence or inflated ego.  Because of that,
> some might find it offensive.

(My emphasis and translation)

Since *trop* means too much, superlative of *très* very, it's possible to say being "too GOAT" is positive.  The "most greatest of all time".  The term originates in sports but has become popular in various contexts.

---

L'argot en anglais très populaire, l'acronyme ***GOAT*** veut dire **"Greatest Of All Time"**. Selon Wiktionnaire :

> (XXIe siècle) De l'acronyme anglais [GOAT](https://fr.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/goat) (Greatest Of All Time, « meilleur de tous les temps »).
>
> (Argot) (Internet) (Par extension) Le meilleur. (Expression
> popularisée sur Twitter, notamment par les Pessi, reprise depuis par
> des journaux, des célébrités…)

Comme *trop* veut dire très très, tout en majuscules pour l'emphase, on dirait que TROP GOAT (ou TROP [l'emoji chèvre]), c'est vraiment tops.  L'origine est dans la domaine des sports.

Mais attention, selon cet article ça pourrait indiquer trop d'arrogance :

> Néanmoins, GOAT n'a pas tout de suite été populaire, les gens ont
> trouvé que le mot était associé à de l'arrogance et à un trop plein de
> confiance en soi. Pour ces raisons, certains peuvent d'ailleurs se
> sentir offensés par l'argot GOAT.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on context, but it's probably positive.

"Trop" can be used colloquially as a response to a question or an affirmation to show strong agreement, meaning something like "so much".

> "This pizza's good!" "So good!!"

> "Elle est bonne cette pizza !" "Trop !!"

It's not super commonly used completely alone but it's possible.

The goat emoji is a reference to the expression "the GOAT", meaning "the Greatest Of All Time". It's also in use on the French internet, mainly in sports but not exclusively.

So maybe it was an answer to the title or the content of the video? I could see it under a video titled "Ronaldo is the best player in the world" for example. It would be useful to have more context to give a more precise answer.